# "I have done every bad thing in the good book" - What does it actually mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

This question might be very specific to a situation in "Revolution" but I cannot understand this sentence.

[image]

From my understanding, he was saying that he has done everything that the book (he believed) said, but it turned out that everything he did was bad. Am I correct?

Answer (score 15):

"The Good Book" is a nickname for the Christian Bible. The caption accordingly means "I have committed every sin named in the Bible."